# What is the process of taking a model with several different parts and materials and baking them onto one map?

Tags: modeling, materials, uv, texture-baking, unity

I have created a high-poly model of a fighter plane that I would like to export into Unity. While I am able to export the model into Unity it does not come with the details and artifacts I applied in Blender.

My research has brought to understand that the textures need to be applied to a single UV map which then can be applied to the model in Unity. Some of the methods I've tried involve joining all objects into one, creating a duplicate of the model and then doing a diffuse bake. However, this results in the map not baking at all or only producing sporadic little spots of the detail to bake.

My question is what are the steps for taking a complex model and baking several textures onto one map for export? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I've added a couple of screen shots to give you an idea of how I've attempted this.

I have my model and a duplicate with the black image texture I've tried to bake onto. The node setup is also for the duplicate model.

I also have my bake setting on diffuse..note the sporadic results on the UV map..I have even tried changing the ray distance with no luck

[image]

[image]

Comment: Care to elaborate what you mean by "high-poly"? (You can use the edit link below your question to add vital information, also screenshots, maybe...) If we are talking about several 10 thousand triangles, it's not exactly efficient to use that in an RT game engine. You might want to bake the details from your high-poly model to a lo-poly version of that model beforehand. In any case, depending on your model, the process of creating game-ready assets is quite a lengthy one and Blender StackExchange is not exactly the perfect platform to create such tutorials.

Comment: Hi metaphor_set, thanks for your reply. I have added some images to hopefully give you some context... Also the model is around 250K verts.

Comment: Again, Blender StackExchange is not the best platform for extensive tutorials. 250 k verts for a game asset are way too much, but then I don't really know anything about your project or the target platform. Look at some detailed [commercial assets](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/vehicles/air/pack-of-19-high-detailed-modern-military-aircraft-low-poly-3d-mo-135663), they don't go over 20k. Look for tutorials about how to bake high-poly to lo-poly. Also, both the hi-poly and lo-poly model should be at the same position for baking.